# Finiteness of integral without using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I want to show that for the following integral in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, we have $$\int_{B(x, 1)}{\ln\frac{1}{|x-y|}dy}<\infty$$ without using polar coordinates. My idea is to write \begin{align}\int_{B(x, 1)}{\ln_{+}\frac{1}{|x-y|}dy}&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\int_{B(x, 2^{-k})\setminus B(x, 2^{-(k+1)})}{\ln\frac{1}{|x-y|}dy}}\\&\leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\ln\left(\frac{1}{2^{-(k+1)}}\right)\mu(B(x, 2^{-k}))},\end{align} but is this finite? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $\ln_+z$ denote? Each argument it receives in this problem satisfies $\ln z\ge0$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will suffice to show that the integral converges when $x=0$ since translation will not affect the convergence. This gives us the integral

$$\int_{B(0,1)}\ln\left(\frac{1}{|-y|}\right)\:dy = \int_{B(0,1)}-\ln(|y|)\:dy$$

which is a strictly positive function on the ball. Notice it will also suffice to show that

$$\int_{B(0,1)}-\ln(|y|)\:dy < \int_{B(0,1)}-\ln(|y|) +\ln(\sqrt{2})\:dy < \infty$$

converges instead, for reasons that will be clear in a moment.

We have that

$$\int_{B(0,1)}-\ln(|y|) +\ln(\sqrt{2})\:dy < \int_{[-1,1]^2}-\ln(|y|) +\ln(\sqrt{2})\:dy$$

since the integrand is strictly nonnegative on both domains. Then we further have that

$$\int_{[-1,1]^2}-\ln(|y|) +\ln(\sqrt{2})\:dy < \int_{[-1,1]^2}-\ln(|y_1|) +\ln(\sqrt{2})\:dy$$

since $|y_1| \leq |y|$ and $-\ln(x)$ is a monotonically decreasing function.

Computing the integral we get that

$$\int_{-1}^1 \int_{-1}^1 -\ln(|y_1|) + \ln(\sqrt{2})\:dy_1 \:dy_2 = 4 + 2\ln(2) < \infty$$

completing the proof.